# Углубленное изучение C

Tags: c, книги

В программировании я не новичок, знаю go, java, c#... но я решил досконально изучить C, в принципе C я +- знаю, но вопрос в тонкостях и систематизации знаний. Мне порекомендовали книгу "Practical C Programming" (но она вроде как старая) и еще есть вариант прочитать стандарт, как вы считаете, какой наилучший способ выучить C?

Спасибо.

Comment: Писать программы и смотреть ассемблерный код, который делает компилятор с разными ключами оптимизации

Comment: А в самом С нет никакой "глубины" чтобы ее учить. Упомянутая книга крайне безобразная. Для расширения кругозора можете ознакомиться с Misra C

Comment: Досконально его никто не знает.

Comment: Вся информация есть в Ричи, язык просто как 2 рубля..... вся соль в идеях реализованных в коде

Answer (score 1):

За долгую жизнь С о нём написано очень много книг. К сожалению, большинство из них либо "для чайников" либо невыносимо скучные. Библию K&R отношу ко второй категории :-) Из того, что читал сам (а прочитать всё я никак не мог) мне понравилась книга

> Харви Дейтел, Пол Дейтел 
>   "КАК ПРОГРАММИРОВАТЬ НА С"

Вроде бы - просто и занимательно, но обсуждаются и достаточно глубокие проблемы С. А на возраст книг по С не смотрите - он и сам совсем не юн!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал

> Дэвид Гриффитс, Дон Гриффитс 
>   Изучаем программирование на С

Книга местит в себе довольно много помимо описания языка: создание своих библиотек , использование make и другое